# How to display number value on top of bar graph for echart-for-react?

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am using https://github.com/hustcc/echarts-for-react for data visualisation. How can I display the exact numbers on top of the bar chart? for example 30,000 on top of the first bar.

[image: Bard graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `label` prop to show the values. Here is a sample config

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
      type: 'bar',
      showBackground: true,
      backgroundStyle: {
        color: 'rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2)'
      },
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top'
      },
    }
  ]
};
```